# python: how do I draw a line graph of the following function?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, probability-distribution

I'm new to python and I am trying to **draw a graph for the probability of normal distribution of 1000 samples** with specific mean and variance. The probability function is:
[image]

I have generated 1000 samples with:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

s_mean = 0
s_variance = 0.1
s_std_dev = np.sqrt(s_variance)
s = np.random.normal(s_mean, 100, 1000)
```

I have managed to follow the function as much as I can:

```
prob_s = (np.exp(-1*((s-s_mean)**2)/(2*s_variance)))/(np.sqrt(2*np.pi)*s_std_dev)
```

and draw the graph using matplotlib:

```
f, (ax1) = plt.subplots(1, figsize=(5, 5))
ax1.hist(prob_s, bins=50, color='r')
plt.show()
```

but the graph is no where close to what I have expected:

[image]

The graph I was expecting is the following:
[image]

I can't find what's wrong here. Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`np.random.normal` needs the mean and the standard deviation. Then `s` can be used as input for the histogram.  `density=True` normalizes the histogram to be similar in size as a probability density function ([pdf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_density_function)), so with an area of `1`.

To draw the pdf curve, you can use your function, using some regularly-spaced x-values.

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

s_mean = 0
s_variance = 0.1
s_std_dev = np.sqrt(s_variance)
s = np.random.normal(s_mean, s_std_dev, 1000)

fig, ax1 = plt.subplots(figsize=(5, 5))
ax1.hist(s, bins=50, color='crimson', density=True)

x = np.linspace(s.min(), s.max(), 200)
prob_s = (np.exp(-1 * ((x - s_mean) ** 2) / (2 * s_variance))) / (np.sqrt(2 * np.pi) * s_std_dev)
ax1.plot(x, prob_s, color='dodgerblue')

plt.show()
```

[image: gaussian normal with histogram]

Answer (score 1):

That won't work. The normal distribution is specific, because it can not be expressed in terms of elementary functions. My advice is to just use scipy.stats

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import scipy.stats as stats
import math

mu = 0
variance = 1
sigma = math.sqrt(variance)
x = np.linspace(mu - 3*sigma, mu + 3*sigma, 100)
plt.plot(x, stats.norm.pdf(x, mu, sigma))
plt.show()
```

if you want to draw the distribution out of those 1000 samples you should use

```
hist, bins = np.histogram(s, bins=50)
plt.plot(bins[1:], hist)
plt.show()
```